# Build to 4-ary tree structure

Tags: java

I want to use Java to create a 4-ary key tree structure as shown in the figure.

How to do ? [this tree structure must be: depth=4 and height= 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB4B8.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own class for that purpose.
Here the node structure wull store the data, and 4 references for its child nodes.

```
//Class to represent 4-ary tree node
class TreeNode<T>
{
    TreeNode<T> firstChild; //store child references here
    TreeNode<T> secondChild;
    TreeNode<T> thirdChild;
    TreeNode<T> fourthChild;
    T data;

    TreeNode(T initData)
    {
        data = initData;
    }
};
```